# Is the following naming convention needed in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My project name is clog, so I named my models and controllers like this: `Clog::User` `Clog::Userscontroller`.

Is this naming convention mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, following the naming convention helps a great deal because not only does rails use it to generate other names, but other gems as well.

Specific to your question, you may be asking if you need to name the controller as UserController given that your model is called User. That is not necessary at all, and you may call it anything else if it better fits your purpose.

In this case, you will probably want to create a few controllers like so:

```
My::AccountController # for e.g.. /my/account
Admin::UsersController # for e.g. /admin/users/1
```

For a user, you refer to your own user record, as 'your account' so this makes more sense. However, the administrator's perspective would be to manage user records. You may also name a controller one thing and serve it under a different route. In your routes file, you may do this:

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :users, :path => "user-accounts"
end
```

To reiterate, your model name need not match up to the controller name. They are only named similarly by association: UserController is understood to handle User records.

Answer (score 2):

No, in a conventional Rails project, that's not necessary. Just name your models and controllers the usual way, like eg User or UsersController.

The other thing is that, when your project grows in size, you may need to organize your models into submodules. One approach to do so is extending your models with app concerns, as show eg [here](http://blog.waxman.me/extending-your-models-in-rails-3) or [here](https://github.com/maprihoda/primal_auth).

As for organizing controllers, one approach is to create a module in the lib directory, which you then include in your ApplicationController, like so:

In `lib/authentication.rb`:

```
module Authentication
  def self.included(base)
    base.send :before_filter, :login_required
    base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token]) if cookies[:remember_token].present?
  end

  #...
end
```

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authentication

  #...
end
```

For this to work, you need to add

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
```

to your `config/application.rb` file

However, if you plan to build your Rails project as a Rails Engine, you may want to follow some naming convention. A good example of a Rails Engine is [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem).